# RaycastHit2D - touch for 2D game

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm trying to build a 2D game for touch devices. Now I'm trying to cast a ray against colliders in the scene to do do something. For example, if hit the ray hit the left button the player move to the left.

I've searched everywhere in the google and youtube but haven't figured how to do this. I'm new to Unity and programming in general, but from what I searched it seems if I want to detect a touch on the screen for a 2D game is more complicated than a 3D game !!!

```
void Update () 
{
 if (Input.touchCount > 0 )
 {
  for ( int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
  { 
   if ( Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
   {
    Ray2D ray = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.GetTouch(i).position);
    RaycastHit2D hit;

    if ( Physics2D.Raycast ( ray, out hit) ) )
    {
     if (hit.transform.gameobject.name == "left")
     {
      // Do Something
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this help but this is how i do it:

```
//Get current worldspace position of mouse cursor
    RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.LinecastAll(clickedPos,clickedPos,theLayer);

    // Copy Linecast to HashSet (unique records), clean out the "Background" GameObject
    foreach (RaycastHit2D arf2D in hits) {
        //linecast_GameObject = GameObject.FindWithTag(arf2D.collider.tag);
        linecast_GameObject = GameObject.Find(arf2D.collider.name);

        //if (linecast_GameObject.name != "Background") {
        if (linecast_GameObject.tag != "Background") {
            linecast_GameObject_HashSet.Add(linecast_GameObject);
            clickedOnTheBackground = false;
        }
        else if (hits.Length == 1) {
            clickedOnTheBackground = true;
            fingerSelection_GO = GameObject.FindWithTag("Dummy_GameObject");
            //fingerSelection_GO = GameObject.Find("Dummy_GameObject");
        }
    }
```